# How do I implement iOS "shake to undo" in Xamarin Forms, only on apple devices?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, prism

This blog describes how to perform [shake to undo](http://conceptdev.blogspot.in/2009/10/monotouch-shake-shake-shake.html), however I'd like to create some kind of base class (in Xamarin forms) that I can reuse this code:

```cs
#region respond to shaking (OS3+)
public override bool CanBecomeFirstResponder {
   get {
      return true;
   }
}
public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
{
   base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
   this.BecomeFirstResponder();
}
public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
{
   this.ResignFirstResponder();
   base.ViewWillDisappear (animated);
}
public override void MotionEnded (UIEventSubtype motion, UIEvent evt)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Motion detected");
   if (motion ==  UIEventSubtype.MotionShake)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("and was a shake");
      // Do your application-specific shake response here...
      Update();   
   }
}
#endregion
```

I'm not sure where to begin... to create a base class that only applies to iOS.

Is there any kind of Dependency injection I can use with XamarinForms for this runtime implementation of a base class for all views?

Comment: you could create a common BasePage class that all your pages inherit from, and them use a custom renderer to add the shake behavior on iOS only

Comment: Where are you implementing Shake To Undo? It is implemented by default for `Xamarin.Forms.Entry` controls for iOS.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick The desired effect is to make this popup for all other cases: `"Would you like to submit a bug report?"`

Comment: Got it! So what you're looking for Xamarin.Forms to display a popup alert anytime the user shakes the device. Is that right?

Comment: LamonteCristo - Let me know if the sample code below is what you're looking to implement! I can always tweak the answer to help you out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explaination

The good news is we can take advantage of the [Device Motion NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.DeviceMotion/) in lieu of Custom Renderers!

We can implement the shake functionality in a base `NavgiationPage` class and use this as our `MainPage`.

I've also included logic in the `App` constructor that only implements the `ShakeListenerNavigationPage` for iOS.

## Code

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using DeviceMotion.Plugin;
using DeviceMotion.Plugin.Abstractions;

namespace YourNamespace
{

    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            NavigationPage navigationPage;
            switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    navigationPage = new ShakeListenerNavigationPage(new MyPage());
                    break;
                default:
                    navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
                    break;
            }

            MainPage = navigationPage;
        }
    }

    public class ShakeListenerNavigationPage : NavigationPage
    {
        #region Constant Fields
        const int _shakeDetectionTimeLapse = 250;
        readonly double _shakeThreshold;
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        bool _hasUpdated;
        DateTime _lastUpdate;
        double _lastX, _lastY, _lastZ;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public ShakeListenerNavigationPage(Page root) : base(root)
        {
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    _shakeThreshold = 20;
                    break;
                default:
                    _shakeThreshold = 800;
                    break;
            }


            CrossDeviceMotion.Current.Start(MotionSensorType.Accelerometer, MotionSensorDelay.Default);
            CrossDeviceMotion.Current.SensorValueChanged += HandleSensorValueChanged;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        void HandleSensorValueChanged(object sender, SensorValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SensorType == MotionSensorType.Accelerometer)
            {
                double x = ((MotionVector)e.Value).X;
                double y = ((MotionVector)e.Value).Y;
                double z = ((MotionVector)e.Value).Z;

                var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

                if (_hasUpdated == false)
                {
                    _hasUpdated = true;
                    _lastUpdate = currentTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    var hasMinimumTimeElapsed = (currentTime - _lastUpdate).TotalMilliseconds > _shakeDetectionTimeLapse;

                    if (!hasMinimumTimeElapsed)
                        return;

                    _lastUpdate = currentTime;

                    var timeSinceLastShakeInMilliseconds = (currentTime - _lastUpdate).TotalMilliseconds;
                    var totalMovementDistance = x + y + z - _lastX - _lastY - _lastZ;
                    var shakeSpeed = Math.Abs(totalMovementDistance) / timeSinceLastShakeInMilliseconds * 10000;

                    Debug.WriteLine($"Shake Speed: {shakeSpeed}");

                    if (shakeSpeed > _shakeThreshold)
                        HandleShake();
                }

                _lastX = x;
                _lastY = y;
                _lastZ = z;
            }
        }

        void HandleShake()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await DisplayAlert("Shake Detected", "You shook your device!", "Ok"));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

## Sample App

Here's a sample Xamarin.Forms app where I implemented this feature!
https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp